# Golang flags takes any arbitrary arguments

Tags: go

I have a program which wraps another executable. I need to provide some interface so that we my program is called, user can provide any arbitrary arguments which will be passed on to the executable that it wraps. For example:

When user calls

```
$ myprogram --call -additional -a -b -c 1 -d=true
```

I would like my program to call

```
wrapped_executable -a -b -c 1 -d=true
```

What is the best way to achieve this using flags package?

Comment: The `flag`-package is order-agnostic. It cannot help you with this unless you put `-a -b -c 1 -d=true` in quotes.

Comment: This is pretty easy if you run it using the shell correctly as `myprogram -call -additional "-a -b -c 1 -d=true"`. Shells break up CLI arguments on spaces.

Answer (score 1):

From the [flag docs](https://pkg.go.dev/flag) docs:

> Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument ("-" is a
> non-flag argument) or after the terminator "--".

so when invoking your outer exe, replace `-additional` with `--`:

```
$ myprogram --call --  -a -b -c 1 -d=true
```

and then to get the arguments after the `--`:

```
flag.Parse()
args := flag.Args() // []string{"-a", "-b", "-c", "1", "-d=true"}
```